# warning division by zero woocommerce category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, division

I'm with this function, on Single Product Page it works fine. But on Category Page it keeps telling me: **'WARNING: DIVISION BY ZERO IN'**. Thanks for any help!

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_sale_price_html', 'woocommerce_custom_sales_price', 10, 2 );

function woocommerce_custom_sales_price( $price, $product ) {

    $percentage = round( ( ( $product->regular_price - $product->sale_price ) / $product->regular_price ) * 100 );

if ($percentage < 0) { return null;}

else {

    if (is_product()) {
        return $price . sprintf( __('<br><span style="font-size:14px;font-weight:bold; color:#ef4136">-%s DE DESCONTO</span>', 'woocommerce' ), $percentage . '%' );}

    else {
        return $price . sprintf( __('<span style="font-size:14px;font-weight:bold; color:#ef4136">-%s DE DESCONTO</span>', 'woocommerce' ), $percentage . '%' );}
    }
}
```

Comment: `$product->regular_price` is zero for this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        function woocommerce_custom_sales_price( $price, $product ) {

       if($product->regular_price > 0 ){ // Do a check if you have set the regular price of product.
            $percentage = round( ( ( $product->regular_price - $product->sale_price ) / $product->regular_price ) * 100 );
}

        if ($percentage < 0) { return null;}

        else {

            if (is_product()) {
                return $price . sprintf( __('<br><span style="font-size:14px;font-weight:bold; color:#ef4136">-%s DE DESCONTO</span>', 'woocommerce' ), $percentage . '%' );}

            else {
                return $price . sprintf( __('<span style="font-size:14px;font-weight:bold; color:#ef4136">-%s DE DESCONTO</span>', 'woocommerce' ), $percentage . '%' );}
            }
        }
```

Comment: It would help if you explained your answer.

Comment: Thanks, the warning is gone. But the calculation isn't working on Categories Page. Its giving me "-[blank]% DE DESCONTO" -> NO NUMBER. But it works on Single Page.

Comment: you mean for the same product you are seeing discount on single page but not on category page ?